# why is there need to set an expiry time for caching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't see this issue explained in the Rails caching guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html, so I wonder if I might ask how caching is working exactly in this example. On my user profile page, I cache the languages the user speaks and set an expiry for 15 minutes. When I did this, I assumed that if the user update his languages before those 15 minutes expired, then the updated languages wouldn't show, because the cache hadn't expired. However, when I test this on my app, the updated languages are showing immediately, so I assume that updating breaks the cache. If that's the case, then why wouldn't I set the expiry date to 1 hour or infinity?

```
  @languages = Rails.cache.fetch("lang", :expires_in => 15.minutes) do
    Language.where({:user_id => @user.id})
  end
```

Note, I'm using Rails 4 with memcached if that's important.

Update, if the expiry time is just about clearing the cache due to size limitations, how long should I set the expiry for?

I have a lot of information (about 15 queries similar to below) on my profile pages that I'd prefer to cache if a user keeps refreshing the page, therefore I was just going to do this

```
 @endorsements = Rails.cache.fetch("endorsements", :expires_in => 15.minutes) do
    Endorsement.where({:subject_id => @user.id})
  end

  @languages = Rails.cache.fetch("lang", :expires_in => 15.minutes) do
    Language.where({:user_id => @user.id})
  end
```

Comment: Most caches are not infinitely large, so having unused keys go away on their own makes life easier.  :)

Comment: Are you testing this in development, or in production?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott I'm in development right now.

Comment: make sure you've set `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` in config/environments/development.rb. That will actually do caching (whereas without it, it does not cache)

Comment: @JesseWolgamott already did thanks. are you surprised by the results noted in my op (that the page updates before cache expires) or was that just a friendly reminder?

Comment: I'm surprised by your results. It's possible it's the rails4 cache-digests at work, but I expect that in the views, not the controller.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott I'm now in the process of changing all user profile controller queries like this  `@answers = Answer.where(:user_id => @user.id).limit(5)` into something like this 
  `@answers = Rails.cache.fetch("answers", :expires_in => 15.minutes) do
   Answer.where(:user_id => @user.id).limit(5)
  end` on the basis that as long as it breaks the cache when the user updates his profile (so that user can confirm with his eyes that updates have been made), then there's no reason not to cache. Would you do that?

Comment: If you're on Rails4 anyway, I would not cache in the controller. Instead, I'd focus on caching using the Russian Doll Caching strategy in cache_digests https://github.com/rails/cache_digests & http://railscasts.com/episodes/387-cache-digests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you need to do in Rails4 to get the caching to work (in development) as you'd expect:

1. Add 'dalli' to your Gemfile
2. add `config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store` to your config/environments/development.rb
3. add `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` to your config/environments/development.rb

(I know you already have #3 done)

Once this is complete, you won't see the "SELECT *" in your logs anymore, and when you update your models, it will not automatically update your cache.

UPDATE:

Like @FrederickCheung says, you need to cache objects, not relations (queries). Best way is to call "to_a" on them.

Comment: I've already done all three (and did them before I wrote the OP)  and I'm getting the results described in OP.

Comment: Try cloning this https://github.com/jwo/so17032870 -- then follow repro steps in readme. Note that it's important that you are caching objects, rather than a query.

Comment: got it to work on my app the way you'd expect after caching objects. Will try your demo tomorrow as well once I get ruby 2.0 installed. Thanks

Comment: I did the three steps in your answer, and with no caching in controller set up caching in the view like this (cache digest)  `<% cache @team do%>
  <h1>Team: <%= @team.name %></h1>

  <%= render @team.members %>
<% end %>` however, I am seeing SELECT (for the data that is supposed to be cached) in the logs every time I load the page .  Is that what you'd expect

Comment: You need to either do caching in the controller, _or_ caching in the views (cache_digests). it's hard to diagnose both. I'm not sure what you're looking for with this question anymore.

Comment: ok, thanks, I just wasn't sure if you're remark about the SELECT referred to caching in the controller (which I've removed) or also applied to caching in the views via cache digest (which you recommended in the comment to the OP) and which I tried

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually caching anything: you are just caching `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects (which is pretty much just a ruby description of a query), rather than the query results itself.

Each time the code runs, this query is pulled in its unexecuted state and then run again. To achieve what you wanted to do, you need to force the query to be executed, for example

```
 @endorsements = Rails.cache.fetch("endorsements", :expires_in => 15.minutes) do
    Endorsement.where({:subject_id => @user.id}).all
 end
```

Cache expiry can be tricky - it's sometimes easier just to have cached items expire automatically rather than ensuring that every single way of changing the data clears the cache. In some cases you may not even know when the data changes, for example if you are caching the results of an external api call.

Comment: but before I started trying to cache I did, for example, `@endorsements = Endorsement.where({:user_id => @user.id})` and I got results, not just a query.  I don't understand why putting almost the exact same code in the cache means I'm just caching the query and not the results `@endorsements = Rails.cache.fetch("endorsements", :expires_in => 15.minutes) do
    Endorsement.where({:subject_id => @user.id})
 end`  why do I need to add the `all` inside the cache code when I didn't use it before?

Comment: because `all` is the thing that makes the query execute.

Comment: At the console, the query gets executed automatically because irb tries to call inspect on the query, which in turn makes it get executed. Doing things like iterating with `each` and so on also make the query execute itself, which is why you didn't need to add `all` before

Comment: thanks for the explanation. So there's no advantage to caching ActiveRecord::Relation?

Comment: No there's no point. Caching the query results can be useful though.